# Can this integral be expressed in terms of elementary functions?

Tags: definite-integrals

Let $\gamma>1$ be fixed. For $1\leq x\leq y\leq \gamma$, I would like to evaluate the following integral :
$$F(x,y)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_1^x\frac{dt}{t\sqrt{t-1}}\arcsin \sqrt{\frac{y-t}{\gamma-t}}.$$
What I know about this are the boundary values :

1) trivially, $F(1,y)=0$;

2) For $y=\gamma$, we have
$$F(x,\gamma)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_1^x\frac{dt}{t\sqrt{t-1}}=\arcsin(1)-\arcsin\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}};$$

3) On the diagonal $y=x$, we have
$$F(x,x)=\arcsin\sqrt{\frac{x}{\gamma}}-\arcsin\sqrt{\frac{1}{\gamma}},$$
as explained in the following post : [evaluation of some integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1214060/evaluation-of-some-integral)

My question is: **For $1<x<y<\gamma$, can $F(x,y)$ be expressed in terms of elementary functions, or is there some simple reason why it cannot?**

If it helps, I also know the partial derivatives :
$$\partial_x F(x,y)=\frac{1}{\pi x\sqrt{x-1}}\arcsin\sqrt{\frac{y-x}{\gamma-x}},$$
and
$$\partial_y F(x,y)=\frac{1}{\pi \sqrt{y}\sqrt{\gamma-y}}\arcsin\sqrt{\frac{y(x-1)}{x(y-1)}}.$$
The first one is trivialy obtained (so it won't help), but the second one requires the evaluation of the integral
$$\int_1^x\frac{dt}{t\sqrt{t-1}\sqrt{y-t}}.$$
This can be done by using Euler substitution method.

Comment: I'm not sure why this was downvoted.

Comment: Try substituting $u=\dfrac{y-t}{\gamma-t}$ .

Comment: @Lucian : I did that and found it remains to compute $$\int \frac{\arcsin(\sqrt{u})   du}{(u\gamma -y)\sqrt{u(\gamma-1)-y+1}\sqrt{u-1}}.$$ I can't see why the problem is easier now...